# Highcharts not working in ie 11

Tags: javascript, highcharts, internet-explorer-11

Please don't say question already asked. I searched alot but faild.

The charts displaying perfectly in chrome, Firefox, and edge but not displaying in IE 11 and less.

here is my code

```
Highcharts.chart('teledensity', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    colors: [graph_data.series_color_one,graph_data.series_color_two,graph_data.series_color_three],
    title: {
        text: 'title'
    },

    credits:{
        enabled:false
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            autoRotation: [0],
            style: {
                fontSize: '11px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        },
        categories: graph_categories,
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'title of y-axis'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function(){

                // var val = this.total;            
                // return (val/1000000).toFixed(2);
            },
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white' 
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'center',
        x: 20,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        // borderColor: '#CCC',
        // borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}',
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function(){
                    var val = this.y;                   
                    return (val/1000000).toFixed(2);
                },
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            },
            treshold: 1
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'series one',
        data: ['1','2','3'],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: '#000',
            fillColor: 'white'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'series two',
        data: ['1','2','3'],
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        },
    }, {
        name: 'series three',
        data: ['1','2','3'],
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        },
    }]
});
```

Comment: any error in the developer tools console?

Comment: is IE11 perhaps in "compatibility mode" for the page?

Comment: no it does not show any error

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle where it works in Chrome/FF and not in IE?

Comment: here is jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ishtiaq123/pq6dh9yp/

Comment: looks the same to me in all browsers

Comment: Ok i find the issue that is with javascript code due to which graph is not loading dynamically only in E 11

here is jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/ishtiaq123/pq6dh9yp/3/ in which code is mentiond 
dont know whats wrong in it

Comment: Just tested in IE11 your demo (https://jsfiddle.net/ishtiaq123/pq6dh9yp/3/) - works fine..

Comment: @PawełFus yes because the value of series provided are static the issue i get is with is map() of javascript which is not working in IE 11

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the series you had given. I just changed your series as following.

```
series: [{
    name: 'series one',
    data: [1,2,3],
    marker: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: '#000',
        fillColor: 'white'
    }

}, {
    name: 'series two',
    data: [4,5,6],
    marker: {
        symbol: 'square'
    },
}, {
    name: 'series three',
    data: [7,8,9],
    marker: {
        symbol: 'square'
    },
}]
```

You can see that, you were given the data as a string data: ['1','2','3']. You can see the updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/pq6dh9yp/2/) here.

Note: If jsFiddle is not loading in your IE browser, please try using [draft version of jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/draft/).

I would also recommend you to style your container div, in your case `teledensity` with some height.

```
#teledensity {
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('teledensity', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'title'
    },

    credits:{
        enabled:false
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            autoRotation: [0],
            style: {
                fontSize: '11px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        },
        categories: ['2015','2016','2017'],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'title of y-axis'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function(){

                // var val = this.total;            
                // return (val/1000000).toFixed(2);
            },
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white' 
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'center',
        x: 20,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        // borderColor: '#CCC',
        // borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}',
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function(){
                    var val = this.y;                   
                    return (val/1000000).toFixed(2);
                },
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            },
            treshold: 1
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'series one',
        data: [1,2,3],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: '#000',
            fillColor: 'white'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'series two',
        data: [4,5,6],
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        },
    }, {
        name: 'series three',
        data: [7,8,9],
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        },
    }]
});
```

```css
#teledensity {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<div id="teledensity"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://highcharts.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved...!

As I was creating graph dynamically and I used .map() which is ES6 not supported by IE11 so I modify code

From

graph_series_data_one   = series_data_one ?>.reverse().map(x => parseFloat(x));
                graph_series_data_two   = series_data_two ?>.reverse().map(x => parseFloat(x));

To

graph_series_data_one   = series_data_one ?>.reverse().map(function (x) { return parseFloat(x); });
                graph_series_data_two   = series_data_two ?>.reverse().map(function (x) { return parseFloat(x); });

and it worked.

Thanks.